# Recursively extract strings between quotes in a given string

Tags: string, perl, extract, quotes

Given a string with substrings within quotes, extract all such substrings

I have written the following piece of code but something tells me that it is ugly (although it does seem to do the trick)

```
my $str = 'printf ("hellp;world", and "this is ; also" and )';

loop:
if ($str =~ /"(.*?)"/) {
    my $substr = $1;
    $str =~ s/"$substr"//;
    print "$substr\n";
}
if ($str =~ /"/) {
    goto loop;
}
```

```
perl quotes.pl
hellp;world
this is ; also
```

So it does work as expected.

Comment: Can the substrings have escaped quotes? E.g. `'printf( "hello \"peter\"", ... )'`

Answer (score 3):

You can do that directly by using the `/g` regex flag in either scalar context:

```
while ($str =~ /"([^"]*)"/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

... or list context:

```
for my $match ($str =~ /"([^"]*)"/g) {
    print "$match\n";
}
```

I've also changed `.*?` to `[^"]*` because it's better to be specific about what you want to match.

`/g` is documented in [`perldoc perlop`](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#Matching-in-list-context):

> The `/g` modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on the context. **In list context, it returns a list of the substrings matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression.** If there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.
>
> **In scalar context, each execution of `m//g` finds the next match, returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.** The position after the last match can be read or set using the `pos()` function; see ["pos" in perlfunc](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#pos). A failed match normally resets the search position to the beginning of the string, but you can avoid that by adding the `/c` modifier (for example, `m//gc`). Modifying the target string also resets the search position.

(Emphasis mine.)